# jQuery wrap each class + class elements ( different classes )

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to wrap each two elements close to each other containing the classes `black` and `blue` in a `<div class="wrap">` across my page.

I tried this, but it doesn't work as I need:

```js
$(".black, .blue").each(function() {
  $(this).next().hasClass('black').wrapAll('<div class="wrap"></div>')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col red"></div>
<div class="col black"></div>
<div class="col blue"></div>
<div class="col red"></div>
<div class="col white"></div>
<div class="col yellow"></div>
<div class="col red"></div>
<div class="col black"></div>
<div class="col bllue"></div>
```

This is my desired output:

```
<div class="col red"></div>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="col black"></div>
    <div class="col blue"></div>
</div>

<div class="col red"></div>
<div class="col white"></div>
<div class="col yellow"></div>
<div class="col red"></div>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="col black"></div>
    <div class="col blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to post my jquery code.

Comment: your code should work, but with .next().hasClass('blue'), and not black. You try to find two black following elements.

Comment: @iguypouf there's a bigger issue there because `hasClass()` returns a boolean, not a jQuery object.

Comment: I just pointed out to remove black by blue, thats it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current approach is flawed as you loop over both the `.black` and `.blue` elements, only try to detect following `.black` elements, and also because you use `hasClass()`, which returns a boolean value, yet try to then call a method on it.

To achieve this you can loop over every `.black` and determine if the `next()` element is `.blue`. If it is you can wrap them both in a `div`, like this:

```js
$('.black').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $next = $this.next();
  if ($next.is('.blue'))
    $this.add($next).wrapAll('<div class="wrap"></div>');
});
```

```css
.red { color: red; }
.black { color: black; }
.blue { color: blue; }
.white { color: white; }
.yellow { color: yellow; }

.wrap { 
  border: 1px dotted #CCC;
  background-color: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col red">Foo</div>
<div class="col black">Foo</div>
<div class="col blue">Foo</div>
<div class="col red">Foo</div>
<div class="col white">Foo</div>
<div class="col yellow">Foo</div>
<div class="col red">Foo</div>
<div class="col black">Foo</div>
<div class="col blue">Foo</div>
```

> Using your example I would like to add a third element having the same class blue.

I assume in this scenario that there may be an unlimited number of `.blue` elements after the `.black`, and they should all be wrapped. In that case use `nextUntil()` along with `:not(.blue)`, like this:

```js
$('.black').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.next().is('.blue')) {
    $this.add($this.nextUntil(':not(.blue)')).wrapAll('<div class="wrap"></div>');
  }
});
```

```css
.red { color: red; }
.black { color: black; }
.blue { color: blue; }
.white { color: white; }
.yellow { color: yellow; }

.wrap { 
  border: 1px dotted #CCC;
  background-color: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col red">Foo</div>
<div class="col black">Foo</div>
<div class="col blue">Foo</div>
<div class="col red">Foo</div>
<div class="col white">Foo</div>
<div class="col yellow">Foo</div>
<div class="col red">Foo</div>
<div class="col black">Foo</div>
<div class="col blue">Foo</div>
<div class="col blue">Foo</div>
<div class="col blue">Foo</div>
<div class="col red">Foo</div>
```

Comment: you have the same answer as me, so i deleted mine. Great explanation also 

Comment: Thanks, it works. Using your example I would like to add a third element having the same class blue. I tried var $next = $this.next().next(); but is not working. Thanks a lot !

Comment: So you mean a `.black` followed by `.blue` and another `.blue`? Is there any limit to the number of `.blue` elements?

Comment: yes this is the limit, black followed by blue + blue

Comment: I added an update for you. It covers a `.black` followed by any number of `.blue` elements

Answer (score 2):

Use `+` **Next Adjacent Selector (“prev + next”)**

```js
$(".black + .blue").each(function() {
  $(this).prev().addBack().wrapAll('<div class="wrap"></div>')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col red"></div>
<div class="col black"></div>
<div class="col blue"></div>
<div class="col red"></div>
<div class="col white"></div>
<div class="col yellow"></div>
<div class="col red"></div>
<div class="col black"></div>
<div class="col blue"></div>
```

Comment: Very nice way of doing it. I'd use this over mine :)